# Rails API carrierwave cannot upload file send from API client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, api

Im using unirest to create a client API in Node JS that will send a data to rails API. I have to change the file into base64 encoded string like this:

```
unirest.post('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/image_uploaders')
.headers({'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'})
.field({ 
    "product_id": 12,
    "variant_id": 1,
    "image": fs.readFileSync(path).toString('base64')
}) // Form field
.end(function (response) {
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

in Rails side this is what handle the request:

```
def create
  variant = Variant.where(id: params[:variant_id]).first

  if variant
    product_image = ProductImage.new
    product_image.image = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(params[:image]))
    product_image.product_id = params[:product_id]
    product_image.variant_id = params[:variant_id]

    if product_image.save
      render json: true, status: :ok
    else
      render json: false, status: :bad_request
    end
  else
    render json: false, status: :bad_request
  end
end
```

I didn't get the file uploaded. Any idea? thanks.

**UPDATE**

I got this error message:

```
undefined method `unpack'
for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe47ac26f80>
```

which point to this line:

```
product_image.image = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(params[:image]))
```

Comment: Show logs from database when you try to save it.

Comment: @MateuszCzerwiński please see my updated question

Comment: Try without `Base64.decode64`, maybe you can store data as base64 (?).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following gem to use base64 encoded string with carrierwave:

https://github.com/lebedev-yury/carrierwave-base64

You would just need to change the `mount_uploader` to `mount_base64_uploader` in your `ProductImage` class, and then you can just assign the base64 encoded string to your image field:

```
product_image = ProductImage.new(params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

I change the:

```
"image": fs.readFileSync(path).toString('base64')
```

to:

```
"image": fs.createReadStream(path)
```

with that there is no need to decode the file. Thanks everyone